# Can we use two pivot in a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

```
Declare @tbl table(SessionId varchar(max),ItemID_FK int,Roles varchar(max))
    insert into @tbl
    select distinct SessionID,ItemID_FK,Roles from tbl_Answers where ID_FK=@ID
    SELECT ItemID_PK,ItemName,case when [Role1] IS NULL then 0 else [Role1] end as [Role1],
    case when [Role2] IS NULL then 0 else [Role2] end as [Role2],
    case when [Role3] IS NULL then 0 else [Role3] end as [Role3],
    case when [Role4] IS NULL then 0 else [Role4] end as [Role4],
    case when [Role5] IS NULL then 0 else [Role5] end as [Role5],
    case when [Role6] IS NULL then 0 else [Role6] end as [Role6],
    case when [Role7] IS NULL then 0 else [Role7] end as [Role7]
    FROM 
    (
    select  items.ItemID_PK ,items.ItemName,count(ans.Roles) as cntRoles,ans.Roles from tbl_Items items Full  join  @tbl ans
    on items.ItemID_PK=ans.ItemID_FK where items.ID_FK= @ID group by Roles,ItemName , items.ItemID_PK
    ) d  PIVOT
     (
          max(cntRoles)
          FOR Roles IN ([Role1],[Role2],[Role3],[Role4],[Role5],[Role6],[Role7])
     ) AS pvt order by ItemID_PK
```

I used the above stored procedure and got the output as

```
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|ItemID_PK |ItemName  |Role1|Role2|Role3|Role4|Role5|Role6|Role7|
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  111     | aaaaa    | 6   |  5  | 0   | 5   |   1 |  4  |  2  |
|  222     | bbbbb    | 1   |  1  | 7   | 2   |   0 |  3  |  1  |
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I have another query and got the following output.

```
Select Category,Answer,Roles
from tbl_Answers where ID_FK=1 and Category='OtherText'

+---------+--------+-----+
|Category |Answer  |Roles|
+---------+--------+-----+
|OtherText| xxx    |Role1|
|OtherText| yyy    |Role1|
|OtherText| zzz    |Role2|
|OtherText| xzx    |Role3|
+---------+--------+-----+
```

I need to merge the above two outputs to generate the result as

```
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|ItemID_PK |ItemName  |Role1|Role2|Role3|Role4|Role5|Role6|Role7|
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  111     | aaaaa    | 6   |  5  | 0   | 5   |   1 |  4  |  2  |
|  222     | bbbbb    | 1   |  1  | 7   | 2   |   0 |  3  |  1  |
|  Null    | Othertext| xxx | zzz | xzx | saa |     | xxx |     |
|  Null    | Othertext| yyy |     |     | zxz |     |     |     |
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

How to combine the second query to the first pivot query to get the result mentioned above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `UNION ALL` to combine the two results, you would need to convert the roles from the top query from int to VARCHAR though:

```
DECLARE @ID INT = 1;

WITH Ans AS
(   SELECT  DISTINCT SessionID,ItemID_FK,Roles 
    FROM    tbl_Answers 
    WHERE   ID_FK = @ID
), PivotData AS
(   SELECT  items.ItemID_PK,
            items.ItemName,
            cntRoles = COUNT(ans.Roles),
            ans.Roles 
    FROM    tbl_Items items 
            FULL JOIN Ans
                ON items.ItemID_PK = ans.ItemID_FK 
    WHERE   items.ID_FK = @ID 
    GROUP BY Roles,ItemName, items.ItemID_PK

)
SELECT  ItemID_PK,
        ItemName,
        [Role1] = CAST(ISNULL([Role1], 0) AS VARCHAR(255)),
        [Role2] = CAST(ISNULL([Role2], 0) AS VARCHAR(255)),
        [Role3] = CAST(ISNULL([Role3], 0) AS VARCHAR(255)),
        [Role4] = CAST(ISNULL([Role4], 0) AS VARCHAR(255)),
        [Role5] = CAST(ISNULL([Role5], 0) AS VARCHAR(255)),
        [Role6] = CAST(ISNULL([Role6], 0) AS VARCHAR(255)),
        [Role7] = CAST(ISNULL([Role7], 0) AS VARCHAR(255))
FROM    PivotData
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(cntRoles)
            FOR Roles IN ([Role1],[Role2],[Role3],[Role4],[Role5],[Role6],[Role7])
        ) AS pvt 
UNION ALL
SELECT  ItemID_PK = NULL,
        ItemName = Category,
        [Role1] = ISNULL([Role1], ''),
        [Role2] = ISNULL([Role2], ''),
        [Role3] = ISNULL([Role3], ''),
        [Role4] = ISNULL([Role4], ''),
        [Role5] = ISNULL([Role5], ''),
        [Role6] = ISNULL([Role6], ''),
        [Role7] = ISNULL([Role7], '')
FROM    (   SELECT  Category,Answer,Roles
            FROM    tbl_Answers 
            WHERE   ID_FK = 1 
            AND     Category = 'OtherText'
        ) pd
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(Answer)
            FOR Roles IN ([Role1],[Role2],[Role3],[Role4],[Role5],[Role6],[Role7])
        ) AS pvt 
ORDER BY ItemID_PK;
```

Note, I have changed this expression:

```
case when [Role2] IS NULL then 0 else [Role2] end
```

to

```
ISNULL([Role2], 0)
```

as the effect is the same, but it is much shorter. I have also removed the table variable, and just placed the same query within a Common Table Expression, as it seems redundant to fill a table variable then only refer to it once. You are removing the use of indexes and statistics on the actual table and gaining no benefit for it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works fine. I didnt think for Common Table Expression.Thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION to combine the two pivots.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Now your answer looks more like a comment.